# Missing getHardwareAddress() method

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I would like to call the getHardwareAddress() method of a NetworkInterface instance in eclipse, but it says "The method getHardwareAddress() is undefined for the type NetworkInterface".

I cant see the getHardwareAddress() method in the list of the NetworkInterface instance's methods when i type dot after its name.

Project build target: Android 2.2
Java Runtime Environment: 6

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The documentation says the [getHardwareAddress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getHardwareAddress%28%29) method appeared in API Level 9. Unfortunately for you, API Level 9 [is supported by Android 2.3 onwards](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html); it's not supported by Android 2.2.

Answer (score 2):

What version of the SDK are you targetting? [getHardwareAddress()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getHardwareAddress%28%29) only exists in API level 9 or higher.